# Linq to Sql doesn't generate the Sql Query I need

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework-6

I'm stuck on a Linq query while using entity framework where the desired query is not being generated. I have abbreviated this somewhat for readability. FYI we're not using .net core and EF is version 6.

I want tsql:
Select col1, col2 from tableX where DatePart(YYYY, col2) = 2021
-- col2 is a nullable DateTime2

The WHERE clause is generating an extra OR line that I don't understand:

```
((DATEPART (year, [Extent1].[col2])) = (DATEPART (year, 2021)))
OR ((DATEPART (year, [Extent1].[col2]) IS NULL) AND (DATEPART (year, 2021) IS NULL))
```

C# code:

```
var myTable = _dbContext.MyTable.Where(x => x.Col2.Value.Year == 2021);
...ToList();
```

Any thoughts as to where the unwanted OR is coming from? Something missing in my C# code?

Comment: `x.Col2.Value.Year == 2021` <= this code may cause problem in "real C#" (System.InvalidOperationException: Nullable object must have a value.) ... you should rather use `x.Col2?.Year == 2021` or `x.Col2.HasValue && x.Col2.Value.Year == 2021` ... maybe it's the cause of "unwanted OR" in generated SQL

Comment: The "unwanted OR" is how the query will handle filtering your result set if you pass `null` (`DBNull.Value`) instead of `2021`.

Comment: also are you sure you have `(DATEPART (year, 2021))` not `(2021)` ? it doesn't make sens ... [it will return `1905`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/135125)

Comment: Sorry my bad, the first part of the code is: DATEPART (year, [Extent1].[col2]) = 2021

Answer (score 1):

I got it working, the problem was a combination of a typo and bad input data.

Comment: This isn't really an answer. You should probably have just left a comment on your original post or delete the original post.